# Unity Input Manager Accessing Specifics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I cannot seem to find much information on this anywhere apart from old posts pointing out that its not possible.

In my game i decided to use the input manager as its there to save time allowing easy configuration of cross platform controls etc. However i have a lot of in game prompts such as "Press "E" to pick up" and so on.

What i would like is to be able access for example my interact button in the input manager so i can display "Press" + Interact Button + "to pick up". I know i could make my own input system which i might end up doing. Although i dont know the answer to this question myself i just cant fathom why unity would not have thought of including this.

Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Yes a lot of people have the same need. But it's on the way - [the last post on Unity blog](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/12/developing-the-new-input-system-together-with-you/) is about new alpha input system which can have customizable keybindings and other cool stuff! Hope it gets integrated soon.

Comment: Currently you will have to use a custom input manager (either your own or one from the assets store).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was said in the comments, your only option as of now is to make a custom input manager. In future versions of Unity there will be support for this but we dont know yet when that will be integrated. Sorry about that.